# how to install mono offline?

Tags: mono, ubuntu-14.04

I am behind proxy and I am trying to install mono by executing the following command on Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS for dotnet development. I am getting into error "gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error". I searched and tried several suggestions but it's not helping.

Is there a way to download this outside proxy and install this offline on my server?

```
ellismg@linux:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
ellismg@linux:~$ echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
ellismg@linux:~$ sudo apt-get update
ellismg@linux:~$ sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

Comment: what I don't understand is: did you configure Ubuntu to use a proxy or not ? Perhaps gpg does use a different setting ? I had similar problems with other applications and trying to grab every dependency for offline installation often is a real pain. My suggestion is: try to make the applications used compatible with your proxy

Comment: yes. I have set the proxy and browse the internet. sudo apt-get update and other operations work fine. I only get error for this.

Comment: did not try this myself but perhaps this one can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53146/how-do-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work-through-a-proxy. It seems to make a difference if you are root or if you get temporary root rights by using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it fails getting the gpg key.

Instead of the first command you can just open https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF in a browser and copy the key into a file. Then run "sudo apt-key add file.gpg"

Answer (score 0):

`sudo <command>` didn't work but it worked when I logged in as `root`.

This is still not the complete solution as root login is not available to all.